# how to efficiently redirect url in Cloudfront without S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

My requirement is to redirect url from Cloudfront. So for this I see there are possibilities to do using Lambda function as mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/handling-redirectsedge-part1/).

My application is not hosted in S3, rather it is hosted in Apache webserver which is running on some EC2 instance.
Because redirect rules are many so I would like Lambda function to read configuration of redirect mapping from some other place but I do not know what could be the other place.  I see it is possible to read either from S3 or SNS topic. Could you please suggest what is the best practice to store redirect mapping and handle redirect via Lambda?

As I understood it is not possible to do using Route53 to read mapping and then do redirect. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I am new to this and would request your expert guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaking some concepts. If I got it right you need a CDN for an Apache server on EC2. In that case you want Cloudfront with EC2 as origin . https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/getting-started/EC2/

Comment: It's worth adding that while every guide you read is probably going to tell you to make an ALB, it's not actually needed so don't be put off by that. If you don't need a scalable application then you don't need the ALB.

Comment: @karjan, thanks, yes Cloudfront with EC2 as origin, but my actual question is different, what is the best practice for redirect in Cloudfront with many redirect rules ( around 1000) ?

Comment: @AlexBailey, could you please point me such guide, as I am learing it will be helpful for me?

Comment: Redirecting is not a feature of Cloudfront, it's just a cache. You can cache a static html page that will redirect your user. Or maybe just use CNAME in Route53. It's hard to tell what your case is with so little info.

Comment: @karjan, I think its possible to redirect in Cloudfront using lambda function as mentioned in my above post

Comment: You can use Lambda @Edge for compute in edge locations. But I still don't get your case